# Grub freezes (and overall glitchy) on fresh 18.04 dual-boot install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, freeze

In short: Grub menu glitches out (arrow down key) jumps the selection from top to bottom.

Selecting anything from the grub menu makes the system freeze (including pressing 'e' to open the editor). I can log-in to the (Ubuntu system only, since, again, selecting anything else from the grub menu freezes the system) if I let it do its automatic countdown and let it boot Ubuntu.

Here is my boot-repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VR9v4pW3VJ/

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my hp server desktop.
Oddly enough, the problem was my Nvidia card.
After removing it, the system worked fine.
Idk if it will work for you, but thats some advice.
If its a laptop or something try reinstalling/updating the drivers I guess?
Idk, hope it works man.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I also think it has something to do with the (video) card. I cannot get the card to show up in any logs (as can be seen in the boot-repair log...

Comment: yeah the card in my computer was a geforce 210, I took it out before putting it back in and installing ubuntu 19.10 and upgrading up to 21.04, it worked, but then I started doing virtual stuff for drum lessons. So it was just sitting upstairs with the card it in (i put windows on it) so idk